# Xerox Phaser 4620 Fuser overheat immediately

Tags: printing, printer, laser-printer, toner

I recently got a Phaser 4620 ans within moments of turning it on, the fuser was marked as overheated and did not even print the test sheet. Anyone else know why this is?

Comment: I am not sure if hardware problem with a printer is even on topic here a Superuser I mean the error itself has nothing to do with the computer that is connected to it.  I suggest you contact xerox for support be sure to check the manual for this likely common problem

Answer (score 2):

Any chance you omitted a step when unpacking it? I've seen plenty of laser printers and copiers that ship with lots of brightly colored plastic tabs and tape strips inside that you're supposed to remove before powering it up; some are not immediately visible unless you know every hatch to open and every plastic flap to flip to find all the tabs. I could imagine leaving something like that in place could cause problems.

Double-check every step of the unpacking/setup instructions to make sure you didn't miss one.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is disengaging the pressure release cam gears (white) separating the Fuser from the Pressure roller on both ends. This can be done by turning a gear on one end of the Fuser. It may be difficult to turn. If it spins then you are on the wrong end of the Fuser and turning the Fuser roller; should be quite easy to turn the Fuser roller without the pressure roller fully engaged.

To turn this same gear to engage the pressure release cam gears for fuser storage is quite hard, unless you know the menu option to do this. I don't.